# Error says http.createServer is not a function but it is

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have this code on a node.js app:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

but I get an error saying createServer is not a function despite you know it is. If I take out the `.Server(app)` then it works but then I cant use express which I need. Any way around?

Thank you.

Comment: You are combining Express stuff with the base node http module. You don’t need .createServer, just app.listen. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: It was originally like that. The problem with this is that if you access `example.com/myapp` without the trailing slash at the end then it says it cant found the application. You have to access like this: `example.com/myapp/` in order to get the page.

Comment: The error specifically says Cannot GET /myapp

Comment: I don't see any /myapp here.  What is mounting your API under that path?

Comment: a script called socket.io. myapp/ is the folder where i installed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since [http.createServer()](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L58) is just a helper method to instantiate a `http.Server`. You can also instantiate using [http.Server()](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L369) function class, so you have two choices.

Option 1.

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(port);
```

Option 2.

```js
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(port);
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  app
</body>

</html>
```

Test:

```sh
 ⚡  curl http://localhost:3000                                            
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  app
</body>

</html>%
```

Comment: The problem is that if you access example.com/myapp without the trailing slash at the end you get an error like this: `Cannot GET /myapp` which forces you to access like this: example.com/myapp/ in order to get the index page.